# Quality degradation with Google TTS service

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm using the Google TTS API, using Wavenet, and without any known reason, the audio returned lost quality and seems distorted. This quality degradation happens occasionally, with different texts, longer and shorter.

You can check the audio
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1te4NE7WcFvHvzfBP4NdO3dyt3EfTj7z_/view?usp=sharing)

The ssml used for it was the following:

```
<speak><prosody pitch='-3st' rate='105%'>Los Angeles on 2020-02-12 and 2020-02-13</prosody></speak>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Google is known for such things, happens in speech recognition too.